# Problem with LogIn logic in C++ password manager

Tags: c++, security, passwords, logic, project

Hi I have a problem with logic in my Login.cpp in a C++ password manager, it says that the correct password and key are incorrect I don't know what to do. I use ARM64 compiler from Xcode and homebrewery and version 20 C++  , the project is a simple password manager I am using a XOR algorithm to encrypt and decrypt password, I ask user for a password and a key to for cipher .

```
#include "Login.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include "Szyfrowanie.h"

namespace login {
    auto loginIn(std::string filePath) -> bool {
        std::fstream file = std::fstream(filePath);
        std::string pass;
        if (!file.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "I can't open the file (Nie można otworzyć pliku)" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        std::getline(file, pass);
        file.open(filePath);

        file.clear();
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        std::getline(file, pass);

        std::string userPassword;
        std::string key;

        std::cout << "Password (Hasło): " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> userPassword;

        std::cout << "Key (Klucz): " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> key;

        std::string globalPass;

        globalPass = cipher::decrypt(pass, key);


        if (userPassword == globalPass) {
            std::cout << "Correct password (Prawidłowe hasło) \n" << std::endl;
            file.close();
            return true;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Not correct password, you have 3 attemps remember (Nieprawidłowe hasło, spróbuj jeszcze raz (masz 3 podejścia wpisania prawidłowego hasła)) \n" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: (Modulo is 128, a key is a word choosen by a user)

Comment: Unrelated: `file.clear();` likely doesn't do what you think it does given how it's bring used. [Here's some good documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) to help you out.

Comment: Why are there two code blocks? Does the first one work and the second doesn't or something? The first one has some interesting file logic with the open, read, open, seek, read sequence. I'd advise getting it to work with plaintext first and then adding encrypt/decrypt. Divide and conquer.

Comment: You don't need `file.close();` before returning either, the destructor will handle that. It's not hurting anything but it is applied inconsistently for the true and false cases.